# PostgreSQL C String to CHARACTER internal representation

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert a C String to character internal representation of PostgreSQL. I am using `bpcharin` function in `varchar.c`. This function requires two arguments : the C String Datum and the `atttypmod`. It is mentioned that `atttypmod` is the declared length of the type plus VARHDRSZ.

My conversion function is:

```
result = DirectFunctionCall2(bpcharin,
                        CStringGetDatum(str),
                        VARHDRSZ + ?);
```

My string `str` value will be one of the column datatype of my table. So, I require the declared column data type length. This information is stored in `character_maximum_length` of `information_schema.columns` view.

My question is, how do I get the `character_maximum_length` in C code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using the `char` data type, you don't need `bpchar`.

A simple `CStringGetDatum` (for `cstring` typed values) or `CStringGetTextDatum` (for `text` typed values) is sufficient.

---

It seems you *are* using `char(n)`, i.e. `bpchar`. Frankly, the best thing to do is *not to do that*; it's a quirky type that should be replaced with a plain `text` or `varchar` in almost all cases.

If you must use it... well, lets take a look at `pg_cast`:

```
regress=> select c.*, tfrom.typname, f.proname 
              from pg_cast c 
              inner join pg_type tfrom on c.castsource = tfrom.oid 
              inner join pg_type tto on c.casttarget = tto.oid 
              left outer join pg_proc f on c.castfunc = f.oid
              where tto.typname = 'bpchar';
 castsource | casttarget | castfunc | castcontext | castmethod | typname | proname 
------------+------------+----------+-------------+------------+---------+---------
         25 |       1042 |        0 | i           | b          | text    | 
       1043 |       1042 |        0 | i           | b          | varchar | 
         18 |       1042 |      860 | a           | f          | char    | bpchar
         19 |       1042 |      408 | a           | f          | name    | bpchar
        650 |       1042 |      730 | a           | f          | cidr    | text
        869 |       1042 |      730 | a           | f          | inet    | text
         16 |       1042 |     2971 | a           | f          | bool    | text
        142 |       1042 |        0 | a           | b          | xml     | 
       1042 |       1042 |      668 | i           | f          | bpchar  | bpchar
(9 rows)
```

There are `castmethod = 'b'` entries for `text` and `varchar`. Per the manual, `b` means:

> that the types are binary-coercible, thus no conversion is required

... so you can use `CStringGetTextDatum` to produce a `bpchar`. However, no length checking will be performed.

If you want type checking you must call the `bpchar` function, which is called on char-to-char casts. It'll do length checking/truncation. It takes three args - the text, the max length, and whether it's an implicit or explicit cast.

e.g. (untested):

```
DirectFunctionCall3( 
      CStringGetTextDatum(my_cstr), 
      Int32GetDatum(max_len),
      BoolGetDatum(false) 
    );
```

The last arg controls the truncation rules; see the comments on `bpchar` in `src/backend/utils/adt/varchar.c` for details.

Comment: I am using a `char` datatype. What should be done in that case?

Comment: @user2761431 Blech - the best thing to do is not use `bpchar`. But see edit above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my issue was finding that `max_len`. Any suggestions there? And, I am using the TPCH database and almost every relation has a CHAR(n) datatype.